# Increase font of HTML in Webview

Tags: webview, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I'm designing Windows 8 Reader app, and i have to use a control to display the HTML content in "Webview". I got this right now. My problem is how to increase the font in the HTML content in webview. I don't how to start this.Can any one help me..

Answer (score 0):

I mainly develop for android. But i do have a friend who had the same problem.. 
What you can do to solve this problem is calling javascript for the webview..

this way you can edit the style of the website from the javascript you call.

But that's the direction i would be looking for now..

**Edit..**

It should be something like this:

```
 YourWebView.InvokeScript("your script", null);
```